# Inversion formula and characteristic functions for a point mass

Tags: probability, statistics, characteristic-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Durett Probability Theory and Examples suggest that the following inversion result (p.95) is intuitive.

However, I cannot figure out how to prove it.

Here is the result :

If $X$ has characteristic function $\phi$, and distribution $\mu$, then :
$$\mu(\{a\}) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T}e^{-ita}\phi(t)dt$$

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: The characteristic function (CF) and the probability density function (PDF) form a pair of Fourier transforms. Usually the CF is considered as the Fourier transform of PDF. The expression you give above simply expresses the PDF as the inverse Fourier transform of CF. You may review any textbook talking about Fourier transform to find the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the proof of inversion formula, let $$I_T = \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\varphi(t)dt = \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T \int e^{-ita}e^{itx}\mu(dx)dt$$

By Fubini's theorem (as $e^{-ita}\ge 0$) and odd property of $\sin$ function, we have: $$I_T = \frac{1}{2T}\int\int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}e^{itx}dt\mu(dx) = \frac{1}{2T}\int\int_{-T}^T \cos(t(x-a))dt\mu(dx)$$ And we can easily observe that the integral $\int_{-T}^T\cos(t(x-a))dt$ is bounded when $x-a$ not equal to zero (because of its periodicity) when $T\to\infty$, and when $x = a$, the integral equal to $2T$. So we have: $$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T\cos(t(x-a))dt = \left\{\begin{aligned}
    &0 , &x\not= a \\
    &1 , &x = a
\end{aligned}\right.$$ Then by BCT, we have $I_T\to\mu(\{a\})$.